# convert 'July 31, 2021' to YYYY-MM-DD format caused ValueError: time data 'July 31, 2021' does not match format '%m %d, %Y'

Tags: python, datetime-format

I have a web app , using Django as backend.
I used `datetime.strptime` function in python3 to convert the date to the format need to input to Mysql database.
But I got the error: `ValueError: time data 'July 31, 2021' does not match format '%m %d, %Y'`

```
end_date = request.GET.getlist('end_date')[0]   # end_date = 'July 31, 2021' in the test case
end_date_converted = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%m %d, %Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

How could I convert `'July 31, 2021'` to `YYYY-MM-DD` format so I could save it to MYSQL date column?

Comment: It's always worth reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) where you will learn that `%m` is expecting a number. Try using `%B` instead [per the docs].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) `%m` is *"Month as a zero-padded decimal number"*, not the month name. You should be using

```
%B %d, %Y
```

as the format specifier. For example:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('July 31, 2021', '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2021-07-31'
```

Answer (score -1):

replace %m with %B which will decode the Month full name